# if then statement in R

Tags: r, sas

I have current SAS code:

```
if variable1 in (1 3) and idnum < 20 then variable1edit = 0.4/sqrt(2);
```

and need to translate this to R code -- how do I create output that will not simply print ".4/sqrt(2)"

Comment: `df$variable1edit[ df$variable1 %in% c(1,3) & df$idnum < 20 ] <- 0.4/sqrt(2)` I think. You can read this as essentially saying "*overwrite variable1edit where these conditions are true with 0.4/sqrt(2)*" It's hard to know for sure with no example data provided.

Comment: Plese provide  an example of code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going from SAS to R I highly recommend using tidyverse, the thought processes are more similar and the workflow is more similar as well.

```
library(tidyverse)

demo <- iris %>%
        mutate(variable_edit = case_when(variable1 %in% c(1, 3) && idnum < 20 ~ 0.4/sqrt(2), 
                                         TRUE ~ NA)
              )
```

This is a 'wordy' answer but I think you'll follow it closely.

EDIT: show [coalesce](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/coalesce.html) function in R

```
mutate(newVariable = coalesce(var1, var2))
```

> Given a set of vectors, coalesce() finds the first non-missing value
> at each position. This is inspired by the SQL COALESCE function which
> does the same thing for NULLs.

Comment: IS there a recommendation for if we want to set the first condition equal to null? ex:  variable = dataset$variable3                                                                        
mutate(variable = ifelse(variable = 'NA', dataset$variable2, dataset$variable3))

Comment: That looks like a coalesce function instead. I'm not quite sure I'm following exactly what you want there though. You can update your question with more details though.

Comment: essentially, I want to create a new variable (hence using mutate) that if the variable 3 value is NA, then use variable 2 value, if it is not NA, use the variable 3 value. Thank you for all of your help so far

Answer (score 0):

Using the ifelse() function, where if the logical condition in the first argument is satisfied, arguement 2 is return, else argument 3 is returned (I used NA because this is most similar to the SAS code which would return missing values `.`)

```
df$variable1edit <- ifelse(variable1 %in% c(1, 3) & idnum < 20, 0.4/sqrt(2), NA)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much. If anyone else has this quandry, this is the code that solved this problem.

mutate(newname = ifelse(variable1 == 1 & idnum < 20,0.4/sqrt(2), variableother))